# don't show images in html or local links in pdf-latex

Tags: org-mode, latex, html, images, pdf

I want to transfer folders with documents with Syncthing to the Android tablet, the documentation is made in orgmode and I export to PDF or HTML. But they don't resolve local addresses in the tablet; neither the images in html nor the links in PDF.
I use relative paths. external links like www works and all works in the desktop.

Some type of links i try

> [[file:./Imagenes/Fuentes-Aduanero.jpeg]] 
> [file:./imagen.png] 
> file:./Imagenes/Fuentes-Aduanero.jpg

some idea?